# WordPress Multisite - Static content - 404 Not Found

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I have installed a Wordpress in a Sub directory called /WordPressDemo.
There is a domain called demo.example.com with the document root / which means that you need to enter demo.example.com/WordPressDemo to access the WordPress.

I use nGINX what causes alot of trouble, I managed to get the basic links (e.g. permalinks) working, so the multisite itself works, the only problem is that it is requesting the static data from the wrong path.

**Example:**

*It requests:* http://demo.example.com/WordPressDemo/MULTISITE-NAME/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11

*but should request*

http://demo.example.com/WordPressDemo/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.11

**My current nginx directives:**

```
   if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;         
            rewrite ^/WordPressDemo(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /WordPressDemo$2 last;      
            rewrite ^/WordPressDemo(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php)$ /WordPressDemo$2 last;
    }


location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /WordPressDemo/index.php?$args ;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
try_files $uri /WordPressDemo/index.php;
include        fcgi.conf;
fastcgi_pass    127.0.0.1:9000;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}
```

Comment: Do you get a 404 for the static files?

Comment: Of course, the location is wrong.

Comment: Seriously? No one can hlp? :(

Comment: Really sad that not even a bounty got me an solution :(

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked into [the Wordpress codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#WordPress_Multisite_Subdirectory_rules)?

Anyway, you may be interested in adapting this code:

```
# WordPress multisite subdirectory rules.
# Designed to be included in any server {} block.

# This order might seem weird - this is attempted to match last if rules below fail.
# http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule
location / {
        index index.php;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}

# Directives to send expires headers and turn off 404 error logging.
location ~* \.(js|css|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|ico)$ {
         expires 24h;
         log_not_found off;
}

location ~ ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/files/(.*)$ {
        try_files /sites/$blogid/files/$2 /wp-includes/ms-files.php?file=$2 ;
        access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
}

#avoid php readfile()
location ^~ /sites {
        internal;
        alias /var/www/mu/sites ;
        access_log off; log_not_found off;      expires max;
}

# Uncomment one of the lines below for the appropriate caching plugin (if used).
#include global/wordpress-ms-subdir-wp-super-cache.conf;
#include global/wordpress-ms-subdir-w3-total-cache.conf;

# Rewrite multisite '.../wp-.*' and '.../*.php'.
if (!-e $request_filename) {
   rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
   rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/wp-.*) $1 last;
   rewrite ^/[_0-9a-zA-Z-]+(/.*\.php)$ $1 last;
}

# Pass all .php files onto a php-fpm/php-fcgi server.
location ~ \.php$ {
         # Zero-day exploit defense.
         # http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,88845,page=3
         # Won't work properly (404 error) if the file is not stored on this server, which is entirely possible with php-fpm/php-fcgi.
         # Comment the 'try_files' line out if you set up php-fpm/php-fcgi on another machine.  And then cross your fingers that you won't get hacked.
         try_files $uri =404;

         fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;


         include fastcgi_params;
         fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

         fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache
         fastcgi_cache_bypass $no_cache;
         fastcgi_no_cache $no_cache;

         fastcgi_cache WORDPRESS;
         fastcgi_cache_valid  6000m;
}

location ~ /purge(/.*) {
        fastcgi_cache_purge WORDPRESS "$scheme$request_method$host$1";
}
```

Does it answer your question?

Comment: No, a copy and paste thing won't help me. I actually need someone who is familar with nginx and wordpress.